# Change a controller's class after inside render

Tags: spine.js

According to the documentation each Spine Controller has a className field that add a class to the rendered element.

```
class Users extends Spine.Controller
  className: "users list"
```

Is it possible to change that after it has been initialized? 
For example, is it possible to change it after an update event to:

```
"users list updated"
```

Thank you in advance for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

to add a new class to it

```
@el.addClass('newCssClass')
```